# locking database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql, locking

I have N processes inserting and updating rows (multiple rows) to a table A in database every t minutes (N > t), say starting at 12:00 AM (all the N processes). I save the last update timestamp in a separate table B to check when was the data last updated.

I'm thinking of getting a read lock to check timestamp and see if data is up to date, if not try and get a lock on the table, update the db and release lock.

Could this be done using linq-to-sql? Is there a possibility of a process acquiring lock and for some reason won't release the lock? In that case, is there a timeout value after which the lock is automatically released?

Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> getting a read lock to check timestamp and see if data is up to date,
>   if not try and get a lock on the table, update the db and release
>   lock.

This is guaranteed deadlock when two processes try to do it simultaneously:

- A gets S lock on the timestamp
- B gets S lock on the timestamp
- A get the X lock on the data
- B attempts to get X lock on data, is blocked by A
- A updates the data
- A attempts to update the timestamp, it needs X lock on it. Is blocked by B's S lock

A is blocked by B, B is blocked by A => deadlock.

> is there a timeout value after which the lock is automatically
>   released

Such behavior would be a complete disaster and make programming transactions *impossible*. What you can ask for, and exists, is for a *request* for a lock to give up if it cannot be obtained in a time out: [`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx).

Is difficult to answer your underlying question because you presented your solution, but not the actual problem you'rte trying to solve. As general comment in databases conditional updates are done in set oriented manner by adding an appropriate predicate, eg. `UPDATE ... WHERE timestamp < @last_timestamp` and let the engine figure out how to implement that correctly.